# Problem with query transition from Oracle to Firebird (Translate -> Replace)

Tags: sql, firebird, translate

At start I just want to say - I'm a self learner of SQL. The program that I use at work, working on SQL Oracle/Firebird database. I write queries to improve my work. Sorry for ugly code.

I wrote a simple query on Oracle that translate code from column kodarin tables spqr. I used "translate" formula. It works perfectly:

```sql
SELECT t.nazwa, s.nrkln, s.datsp, s.ilosp, k.seria
FROM spqr q, sprz s, towr t, kzak k
WHERE TRANSLATE(kodqr,
    '76543210?>FEDCBA@ONMLKJIHWVUTSRQP_^]ZYX89',
    '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]^_?>'
) like '%'||:teks1||'%'
and s.id=q.idsprz and s.idfirm=q.idfirm
and t.idfirm = s.idfirm and t.id = s.idtowr
and s.idtowr = k.idtowr and s.idfirm = k.idfirm and s.idkzak=k.id
```

Now I want to do similar thing on Firebird.

Can someone help me with this?

I tried do it with multiple "replace" function it works but some of characters are translated and some not. Also this one won't work without "min" statement - its give error:

> single-row subquery returns more than one row

```sql
SELECT t.nazwa, s.nrkln, s.datsp, s.ilosp, k.seria
FROM spqr q
JOIN sprz s ON (s.id = q.idsprz AND s.idfirm = q.idfirm)
JOIN towr t ON (t.id = s.idtowr AND t.idfirm = s.idfirm)
JOIN kzak k ON (s.idtowr = k.idtowr AND s.idfirm = k.idfirm AND s.idkzak = k.id)
WHERE
((SELECT min(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
       REPLACE(
    kodqr,'7','0'),'6','1'),'5', '2'), '4', '3'), '3', '4'), '2', '5'),
    '1','6'),'0','7'), '8', '?'), '9','>'),
    'A', 'F'), 'B', 'E'), 'C', 'D'), 'D', 'C'), 'E', 'B'), 'F', 'A'),
     'G', '@'), 'H', 'O'), 'I', 'N'), 'J','M'),
    'K', 'L'), 'L', 'K'), 'M', 'J'), 'N', 'I'), 'O', 'H'), 'U', 'R'),
     'P', 'W'), 'R', 'U'), 'S', 'T'), 'T','S'),
    'Q', 'V'), 'W', 'P'), 'X', '_'), 'Y', '^'), 'Z', ']'), 'V', 'Q'),'S','T'),
    '>','9'),'_','X'),'?','8'),'@','G'),'^','Y'),']','Z'),'7','0'),'',''),
    '6','1'),'2','5'),'0','7')) from spqr)) like '%'||:teks1||'%'
GROUP BY t.nazwa, s.nrkln, s.datsp, s.ilosp, k.seria
```

I tried version with "case" function - this one I couldn't make to work.

Comment: Why are you using a select in the `WHERE` clause in your Firebird variant? That is entirely unnecessary (and then would also eliminate the need for using `MIN`), and will also produce the wrong result compared to your Oracle version of the code.

Comment: Better, if I use it right after main select?

Comment: You shouldn't need it at all. Just `where REPLACE(REPLACE(... (q.kodr, ...), ...), ...) like '%'||:teks1||'%'` should do the trick.

Comment: This come with error: "invalid relational operator".

Comment: Ok, i was able to run it (my mistake i forgot to delete "from spqr).
But now why some replace function works and others dont?

Comment: The problem with some characters working and others not is because you're replacing some characters with another, and then back (e.g. you're replacing `7` with `0`, and then replacing `0` with `7`. That means all characters which were originally 7 and all characters that were 0, will end up being 7.

Comment: BTW: The simpler solution is probably to do the necessary transformation on the parameter value, and then query the column in its original encoded form.

Comment: That's is good idea, but how I can avoid same problem with "replace" parameter value.

Comment: I think the solution presented by l487804 in their answer is the only way forward, or you need to add another layer of complexity by replacing to an intermediate value before replacing to a final value.

Comment: I resolved this by doing "ciphering" outside SQL. I create VBA macro in Google Sheets thats give me code and then i past it to query.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is the following function @Mark Rotteveel wrote in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29576235/7481126

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION TRANSLATE_func
   (text varchar(10000), 
    toReplace varchar(10000), 
    replacePattern varchar(10000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
   declare variable resultat varchar(100);
   declare variable cut varchar(100);
   declare variable i integer;
   declare variable position1  integer;
   declare variable letter  varchar(100);
   declare variable lenght integer;
BEGIN
   i = 1;
   resultat ='';
   lenght =  char_length(text);
   while(i <= lenght) do
   begin
       cut = substring(text from i for 1);
       position1 = position(cut, toReplace);
       if (position1 > 0) then
       begin
           letter = substring(replacePattern from position1 for 1);
           resultat = resultat||''||letter;
       end
       else 
       begin
           resultat = resultat ||''|| cut;
       end
       i = i+1;
   end
   return resultat;
END
```

Comment: My answer there is just a fixed version of the code in the question, so most credit should go to [Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4655594/tom).

Comment: Unfortunately, program that I work on, do not allow this kind of function. I need to do all in one query.

Comment: @Tuathe Why can't you add a function and use that?

Comment: It's a closed program, used for management of pharmacy :) He works on SQL database. As userI can write queries to help me with work but some functions of "normal SQL" are blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by doing "ciphering" outside SQL. I create VBA macro in Google Sheets thats give me code and then i past it to query.